# Debugging Static Libraries on Xcode

Tags: debugging, static-libraries, xcode5

I have multiple static libraries (.a) combined into a single fat universal static library using lipo and included into an iPhone Xcode project. For example, lib1.a, lib2.a, lib3.a are combined to form a single library called libMyFatLibrary.a.

All the projects are included into the Xcode project. When I set a breakpoint in .cpp file from lib1.a, it is not breaking. Do I have to change any xcode settings? I am using Xcode 5.0.

Note: All my libraries are built with debug symbols.

Comment: are you libraries built with debug symbols?

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes, all my libraries are built with Debug symbols.

Comment: @GradyPlayer your comment about "debug symbols" saved my life. THANK YOU!

Comment: how does Debug Symbols help with debugging of static libraries?